# FMOD, Beats Per Second

Tags: c#, c++, fmod

Using `FMOD` (interactive audio middle ware), is it possible to calculate the Beats Per Second of a track in real time as it is playing?

I am unable to find much information about this, it would be very useful. Will be using `c#` but will be able to translate.

Thanks

Comment: I assume you're talking about [the interactive audio middleware](http://www.fmod.org/) and not [the floating-point modulo operation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod)?

Comment: ahh yes, apologies, the interactive audio middle ware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FMOD doesn't provide any mechanism to calculate beats per minute, you would need third party software to achieve that.